# how to send gestures under navigator?

Tags: flutter

i make an app and some application with fluter.
i have a touch-able widget on background, and a navigator is stacking on that widget like below code.

```
void build(context) { 
   return Stack(
      children : [
         MyWidget(),
         Navigator()
      ]);
}
```

i want to through-pass all gestures witch Not covered with Navigator's widget.
but navigator has gesture detector, and it consume all gestures.
there is no way pass gestures to MyWidget()?
ignorePointer is not a answer because in navigator page routes are full screen or half-covered ui so touch covered area are touch-able.
how can i do it?

Comment: Did you manage to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with a GestureDetector if you don't want to have the clicking animation and with an InkWell if you do want.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html